# Prove that $G/N \simeq GL_n(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given field $F$, define $T_{A,w}:F^n\to F^n$ by $T_{A,w}(v)=Av+w$ where $A\in M_n(F)$ and $w\in F^n$.

Define $G=\{T_{A,w}|A\in GL_n(F),w\in F^n\}$ and $N=\{T_{I_n,w}|w\in F^n\}$.

The first two parts of the question were to prove that $G$ is a group, which I did by proving that $T_{I_n,0}$ is neutral and $T_{A^{-1},-A^{-1}w}$ is inverse to $T_{A,w}$ in $G$ (I'd appreciate confirmation of this), and to prove that $N$ is a subgroup in $G$, which I did by showing that $gfg^{-1}\in N$ when $g\in G,f\in N$.

The next part is to prove $G/N \simeq GL_n(F)$, and I'm completely stuck here - I've attempted to manually define an isomorphism, but each of my attempts have been either non-injective or non-surjective.

Comment: Do you know the first isomorphism theorem?

Answer (score 0):

The map $G\to GL_n(F)$, $T_{A,w}\mapsto A$ seems to suggest itself.
You need to show that it is

- well-defined,
- homomorphic,
- is onto
- and has precisely $N$ as kernel.